# Unable to create a constant value of type {x}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I was updating a table with the following Code :-

```
var dataUpd = (from A in ctx.tbl1
               from B in ctx.tbl2
               from C in ctx.tbl3
               where A.CompanyId == B.CompanyId
                     && A.ShiftId == B.ShiftCode 
                     && A.EmployeeId == C.EmployeeId 
                     && A.ShiftDate == C.Time_Date1
               select new { A, B, C });
foreach (var row in dataUpd)
{
    row.C.Time_Field1 = row.A.ShiftId;
    row.C.Time_Field2 = row.B.Status.ToString();
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I Just changed the `ctx.tbl3` to a Model List like this :-

```
public List<TO_TempInOut> listTempInOut = new List<TO_TempInOut>();
........ Changed in Query - listTempInOut is filled with data
 from C in listTempInOut
```

Gives me Error :-

> Unable to create a constant value of type TO_TempInOut.  Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

How to solve this Error?

Comment: of type TO_TempInOut. We are joining list with sql table.

Comment: Sounds like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#Anchor_4

Comment: Previously i was updating in the sql table. Now i need to update the list `TO_TempInOut`.

Comment: @Anup  LINQ does *not* update anything. It's only a query language. You probably confused Entity Frameworks calls like `SaveChanges` for LINQ. Post the code that actually produces the error, not the EF code that you thought was doing the same thing

Comment: @Anup btw you can't join a list with a table. Please post the actual code, it's impossible to help without any clues.

Answer (score 1):

You cann't write a Linq Query Mixing "primitive types or enumeration" - (it means here your local list/enumeration variable) and Sql Tables. Because it is not possible to make join like this.Entity framework first creates a sql query from your code.

So, use either context (database) variables or local variable. You can write two separate query for this purpose. One for get list from your database. Then again filter that list with your "TO_TempInOut" list.